# find the limit of $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{2xy^3+x^2y^3}{x^4+2y^4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

find the limit of $$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{2xy^3+x^2y^3}{x^4+2y^4}$$
I have absolutely no idea how to proceed with that. I would prefer a solution that would involve use of squeeze theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y=kx$. So,
$$
\frac{2xy^3+x^2y^3}{x^4 + y^4} = \frac{k^3x^3(2x+x^2)}{x^4(1+k^4)} = \frac{k^3}{1+k^4}(x+2)
$$
and limit depends on $k$; so, it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 3):

A start: The limit does not exist. For imagine that we travel towards $(0,0)$ along

(i) $x=0$ or (ii) $x=y$.